# In search of teeny tiny stopwatches for mice

Tags: story-identification

In my memory of The Demolished Man, the idea of 'tensor said the tensor' is accompanied by another jingle that involves, I thought, 'teeny-tiny stopwatches for mice.' Now, maybe it's in there, but not mentioned on the internet, or maybe it's somewhere else and I've made a bad connection, or maybe I dreamed the whole thing.

Comment: I can't see anything that remotely matches this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Larry Niven's Children of the State, there's

> “Oh, we got a new computer, but it's quite a disappointment," Ktollisp sang, “‘cause it always gives this same inane advice: Oh, you need little teeny eyes for reading little teeny print like you need little teeny hands for milking mice!"

But this does seem like a long shot as it has nothing to do with Alfred Bester except being a bit of a brain worm. (I think this has been used elsewhere, but I can't remember where.)

Comment: And yet, I think you got it!